# Mobile Safari (iOS6) does not change viewport width on the *second* rotation. Why?

Tags: javascript, ios6, orientation, mobile-safari, landscape

We have a responsive web site http://www.thinglink.com that is supposed to look just fine whatever the web browser with is. For iOS devices we use viewport metas:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Now strange things happen if you rotate iPhone several times:
1. Start with portait. Everything's fine. window.innerWidth is 320px
2. Rotate to landscape. Everything's fine, window.innerWidth is 480px
3. Rotate to portrait. Everything's fine, window.innerWidth is 320px
4. Rotate to landscape again. Page looks zoomed in (and you can pinch-zoom out to normal), window.innerWidth stayed at 320px..

It looks like after second rotation iOS forgot to resize-zoom the page properly. 
Why? Has anybody else seen similar issue?

P.S.
For iOS5 devices we also used to utilize https://github.com/scottjehl/iOS-Orientationchange-Fix but it's supposed to be not needed anymore and it doesn't help anyway.